# how is it possible to dynamic route

Tags: laravel, routes

I want to get a dynamic route function into Laravel 6.x

```
Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
Route::get('/{code}', 'DetailController@detail1')->name('detail1');
Route::get('/impress', 'ImpressController@index')->name('impress');
```

If the URL contains a code with 4 digits, DetailController@detail1 should be called.
If the URL contains a code with 8 or 9 digits, DetailController@detail2 should be called.
However, it should still be possible, for example, to call the imprint controller.

How can this be realized?

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 2):

You should use regex to define the constraint on your parameter:

```
Route::get('/{code89}', 'DetailController@detail1')->where('code89', '[0-9]{8,9}')->name('detail2');
Route::get('/{code4}', 'DetailController@detail1')->where('code4', '[0-9]{4}')->name('detail1');
```

See : https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints

Define them in this order or detail1 will always be matched and never detail2.

Comment: i can only get to `detail1` with this setup

Comment: Ok. Solved. I did not test and the router needs to have a different name for the parameter `code` if it's not the same... I've edited my answer to use code4 and code89 depending on the parameter length.